# v-for index not showing in component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue component where I want to print index of each item. This component is used in parent component with `v-for` like

```
<WorkCard v-for="(obj,index) in work_item_list" v-bind:key="index"></WorkCard>
```

Now in child component `WorkCard.Vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="work-card mt-2 mb-2">
              <span>{{workItem.work_title}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="border border-info">{{index}}</div>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
 name: 'WorkCard',
 props: {
   workItem: {type: Object, default: null},
   //also tried as following
   //index:{type:Number,default:0}
 }
```

This `index` never showing. When try `index:{type:Number,default:0}` then always print `0`.
My `work_item_list` in console

[image]

Comment: Where are you binding the `work-item` prop? You don't appear to be binding any props so of course you'll only get the default value

Comment: Works fine here when you actually bind the props ~ https://jsfiddle.net/bsor24kx/

Comment: @Phil there are 3 component in my app. parent component `props` getting well in immediate child but in last child I tried `this.$parent.workItems` this also works but only `index` not showing. Showing this error `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587 [Vue warn]: Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

Comment: I really don't know what you're saying there but you should never be accessing `this.$parent` data.

Comment: @Phil Can you describe how can I access parent component data into nth child?

Comment: Pass it down through props or alternately, use a central data store like Vuex. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Answer (score 3):

pass the work_item_list as prop to the child component and do the looping there.

Eg

In Parent

```
<WorkCard :workitem="work_item_list"></WorkCard>
```

In Child

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(obj,index) in workitem" v-bind:key="index">
        <div class="work-card mt-2 mb-2">
              <span>{{obj.work_title}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="border border-info">{{index}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: The prop name in the template should ideally be `work-item` as it's unlikely OP is using string templates

Comment: not working, props data are not passing into child component, My parent component is `a` then child `b` & then b's child `c`. data are coming into `a` to `b` but not into `c`

Answer (score 2):

If your props is `index` then you have to bind `index`.

```
<WorkCard
  v-for="(obj,index) in work_item_list" 
  v-bind:key="index"
  v-bind:work-item="obj"
  v-bind:index="index" // add here
</WorkCard>
```

Comment: 28 tried, not working. Showing `0` which is default